# how to validate and check if a entered URL is valid or not in Drupal 6

Tags: url, drupal-6, drupal-modules

Without using any third party modules, is it possible to validate and check at the same time if any URL entered in a text-box is valid or not in Drupal 6 ? Some sample code will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[menu_valid_path()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_valid_path/6) function in menu.inc (which is part of Drupal Core) does just that.

To answer your specific question:

> Without using any third party modules, is it possible to validate and check at the same time if any URL entered in a text-box is valid or not in Drupal 6

**Yes.**

You will, however, need to create a simple custom module.

Let's assume:

1. Your [form id](http://www.lullabot.com/articles/modifying-forms-drupal-5-and-6) is `my_form_1`
2. The field name in question is my_path_field_1

In your MODULENAME.module file:

```
<?php
/**
 * Modifies the existing form element 'my_path_field_1' to add
 * 'MODULENAME_path_validate' function to validation array.
 * 
 * (MYMODULE_path_validate is defined below)
 */
function MODULENAME_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  switch ($form_id) {
    case 'my_form_1' :
      $form['my_path_field_1']['#element_validate'] = array('MODULENAME_path_validate');
    break;
}
// Note, you could use hook_form_FORM_ID_alter(&$form, &$form_state)
// instead of the above to simplify things if the only thing this module
// does is validite one field for a valid path.

/**
 * Validates the my_path_field_1 using Drupal's built-in menu_valid_path()
 * function. Returns a form error if the field does not contain a valid path
 * or the current user does not have access to the path's permission.
 */
function MODULENAME_path_validate($element, &$form_state) {
  if (!menu_valid_path($element)) {
    form_error($element, t('The path entered does not exist or you do not have permission to access it.'));
  }
}
```

Comment: This does not appear to work. If I enter a link that should 404 it will still be valid.